# Symfony2: Weird route not found error

Tags: php, symfony

So I have it defined as:

```
/**
 * Class TemplateController
 * @package TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle\Controller\API
 * @Route("/api/v1/templates")
 */
class TemplateController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("?available={id}")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function findAllAction($id)
    {
        echo "Yu";
    }

/**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @param $id
     * @param $template_name
     * @return Response
     */
    public function findAction($id)
    {}
}
```

When accessing it as: `http://localhost/api//v1/templates?available=1` it says no matching route found. Where am I doing wrong? The other route works fine.

Comment: Just specify you route for action like this: `@Route("/")` and handle your request with `$request->query->getInt('available')`. Or you could use `@Route('/available/{id}')` instead. Don't see any clue to make this route with get-parameter inside.

Answer (score 1):

Your base route for your controller is defined as `@Route("/api/v1/templates")`, but you're only calling "/api/templates/*". You simply forgot the "/v1/" in there.

Try calling `http://localhost/api/v1/templates?available={id}`.

---

Please note: on the CLI you can always dump all registered routes for easier debugging. Just type:

```
$> app/console debug:router

# or bin/console if you're using Symfony3 and above
$> bin/console debug:router
```

Comment: Sorry I put wrong one. I just corrected. It is not accepting `?` at all

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
http://localhost/api/template?available=1
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/api/templates?available=1
```

check your controller class and word used in the URL.

Comment: No. Check the base route above class.